# How to get two fields based off a most recent date attribute?

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

A Billing table, and a Customer table.
The Billing table and customer table both share a common attribute of Customer Number.
Billing Table

I'm trying to create a view that will retrieve the customer code and bill number for the **most recent** invoice date. I'm having trouble ordering my query.

This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE VIEW RECENT_ORDER
AS 
SELECT 
c.Customer_Num, b.Bill_Num
FROM CUSTOMER c 
INNER JOIN BILLING b ON c.Customer_Num = b.Customer_Num 
WHERE c.Fname='Jess' AND c.Lname='Hanks'
HAVING MAX(b.Bill_Date);
```

I have also tried putting the 'HAVING' portion as a WHERE statement.

Comment: `HAVING MAX(b.Bill_Date);` is invalid SQL to begin with. `having` needs a boolean expression, but `max(bill_date)` returns a DATE value

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

This should get your answer:

```
CREATE VIEW RECENT_ORDER
AS 
SELECT c.customer_num, b.bill_num 
FROM customer c
JOIN billing b ON c.customer_num = b.customer_num
WHERE b.bill_date = 
(SELECT MAX(bill_date) FROM billing WHERE customer_num = b.customer_num)
AND c.Fname='Jess' AND c.Lname='Hanks'
```

Though normally I wouldn't expect to create a view that limits results to just one customer!?  Remove the last line `AND c.Fname ...` if you intend to get the most recent result for any/all customers.  Note that you may get multiple results for a customer if they have more than one invoice on the same date.